# Actual infinite vs. Potential infinite

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, infinite

I'm looking for bibliography about the problem of **Actual infinite vs. Potential infinite.** I would appreciate information about papers or books treating this problem deeply, philosophical and historical remarks.

Comment: If you're just looking for a bibliography, can't you use Google to find some references? I'd start with SEP and Wikipedia. http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-mathematics/

Comment: I've already done it. But i would appreciate some guidelines from someone with experience in investigation about this problem.

Comment: you can try with : AW Moore, [The Infinite](http://www.amazon.com/Infinite-Problems-Philosophy-W-Moore/dp/0415252857/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1402434380&sr=1-1&keywords=AW+Moore+The+Infinite) (1990).

Comment: What is actual and potential infinity? I got lost.

Comment: @Asphir Dom - The distinction traces back at least to Aristotle : the succession of natural numbers is fr sure *potentially* infinite, because for every number you can think of or state, you can always add +1 to it getting a bigegr one. Potential infinite means "unlimited possibility of iterating a process". *Actual* infinity is something (cosmos, God, alef_0) which is infinite and we assume that it is "really" existsing "all together" somewhere : in the real world, in the mind of God, in the platonic heaven ...

Comment: I'm just looking for bibliography about that topic. Why is it too broad to answer in a few paragraphs? Mauro did.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with [Continuity and Infinitesimals](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/continuity/) with bibliography, both for the mathematical and the philosophical sides of the problem.

From the same author, you can find a book-lenght version of it : John Bell, [The Continuous and the Infinitesimal in Mathematics and in Philosophy](http://publish.uwo.ca/~jbell/The%20Continuous.pdf) (2005).

In addition to AW Moore, [The Infinite](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415252857) (1990), I suggest also Shaughan Lavine, [Understanding the Infinite](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005BBMPB0) (1994).